# Windows Server 2016 network resets after installing the Hyper-V role

Tags: windows-server-2016, server-settings, hyper-v-server-2016

On a new installation of **Windows Server 2016 Datacenter** desktop edition, I set up the networking to manual and assign all the IP addresses, then install the *Hyper-V* role. After the installation completes and it's done rebooting, the server loses its networking settings. It defaults back to *DHCP*, therefore, I need to go back and reset the networking IPs.

I also tried to add the server to the domain after setting up the IP and before installing *Hyper-V*, and still, same behavior.

I installed no updates so far on any of my systems.
I encountered this on all the 2016 servers I installed.

Is there a fix or Windows update to correct this issue?
This is something I haven't experienced on any of the previous Window Server releases.

Answer (score 0):

How far did  you get into Hyper-V setup?  After installing the role you will almost always need to setup virtual switches, link aggregation, virtual network adapters, and so on.  The creation of all these various components will result in static addresses associated with the the physical interfaces being dropped.

Setting the static addresses should be one of the last steps you do after you have configured any link aggregation and virtual switches, management interfaces and so on.

Comment: If you attach a virtual switch to a physical network adapter then the virtual switch does consume the adapter.  I'm pretty sure there is a warning box that pops up saying you are going to interrupt the network when you do this.  I'm also pretty sure that this is the same exact behavior from 2008 and up.  However I use a dedicated management port so I never lose all my settings/connectivity.  I thought if you checked allow management it would create a virtual adapter for the host to use and fill in the properties for it from the consumed adapter, but it's been a long time.